# How to calculate the carry-on in multiplication circuit

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I am trying to convert integer factorization to sat-3 by using a multiplication circuit. My first step is to convert the multiplication circuit into [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).

I best understand via examples so I started with $5*7=35$. I converted it to binary.

```
   101
   111
   ---
   101
  101
 101
 -----
100011
```

And now I am trying to represent it in a generic way. For a given integer $C$ with $2n$ bits, $C=(c_1,c_2,⋯,c_{2n})$. I am interested in finding two integers $A=(a1,⋯,a_n)$ and $B=(b_1,⋯,b_n)$ whose product is $C=A∗B$.

Continuing with my example I am getting something like that:

```
a_3 a_2 a_1
b_3 b_2 b_1
-----------
```

- $c_1 = 1 = b_1 \land a_1$
- $c_2 = 1 = b_2 \land a_1 \oplus b_1 \land a_2$
- $c_3 = 0 = b_3\land a_1 \oplus b_2\land a_2 \oplus b_1\land a_3 \oplus (b_2 \land a_1 \land b_1 \land a_2)$
- $c_4 = 0 = b_3\land a_2 \oplus b_2\land a_3 \oplus (carry-on)$
- $c_5 = 0 = b_2\land a_3 \oplus (carry-on)$
- $c_6 = 1 = (carry-on)$

As you can see I got stuck with the carry-on, can you please help me to complete my example and tell me what is the general rule for it.

Comment: Are you asking for fixed size integers, or arbitrary integers? It can be done in many ways, a combination of shifts & adders is a reasonable first cut.

Comment: @copper.hat, sorry I don't know the difference between the two. My final goal is to find factors of big integers using CNF. For this question, I need help with the definition of the carry-on in a multiplication circuit via CNF.

Comment: So, given two $n$ bit integers you want a circuit with $2n$ bit output that computes the multiplication? You do realise that the expressions will be huge? This is really a hardware synthesis question.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, I do realize that it will be huge, but before I search for optimizations, I want to understand the core idea. I need help with replacing the $(carry-on)$s in my example with the right expression and show me the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Generate code for a two bit adder with carry in and carry out. Combine to create a $2n$ bit adder. Create code for a $2n$ bit shifter. Combine to create a multiplier. Now flatten the circuit to get expressions for each bit.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know how to calculate $c_4$ in my example because I don't know how to calculate the carryout from $c_3$. And same for $c_5$ and $c_6$

Comment: It's probably too trivial for you so you don't even consider it, but for me, I just don't get it.

Comment: Can you create the circuit that adds two bits & carry in and generates a sum & carry out? There are many solutions (all functionally the same obviously).

Comment: @copper.hat no, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: A basic one bit with carry-in circuit is $s = a\oplus b \oplus c_\text{in}$, $c_\text{out} = ab + a c_\text{in} + b c_\text{in}$. You can combine them to make a $2n$ bit adder. A shifter should be straightforward. Then combine in the obvious shift & add way. It is straightforward but there are a lot of expressions.This is just basic digital logic design.

Comment: @copper.hat so can you complete $c_4$ in my example?

Comment: You need to do you own work :-).

Comment: @copper it's not homework. I learn via examples. So I need a solution for it to understand.

Comment: Perhaps you could study some Boolean logic synthesis? I am happy to assist but I am not going to spend my Sunday synthesising a 4-bit multiplier for your convenience. It is simple but very tedious. You need to compute the **two** carry out bits from adding the carry out of adding $a_2 \land b_1$, $a_1 \land b_2$ to the sum of $a_3 \land  b_1, a_2 \land  b_2, a_2 \land  b_3$.

Comment: @copper.hat Well thank you for the help that you gave me. I guess I will wait to place a bounty on this one.

Comment: This may not assist, but indicates how people design digital multipliers: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~eecs151/sp18/files/Lecture21.pdf (p.7 is an unsigned $4 \times 4$ bit combinational multiplier.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiplication circuit"? Something like this? https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/c8/c8s2/c8s2v4/binary-multiplication-6-03-/